# Does the federal reserve create any type of deadweight/welfare loss?

Tags: macroeconomics, interest-rate, investment, federal-reserve, financial-markets

In microeconomics, we learn that when a good is overproduced or under produced, there is a dead weight loss associated with it. It seems like the same concept would apply to macroeconomics, where the Federal Reserve, by pumping money into the financial market, creates artificially low or high interest rates and causes spending on investment below or above what it would be naturally. Do these interest rate changes cause any type of microeconomic welfare loss?